# how do i insert multiple values in mysql and avoid duplicates

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

How would I insert multiple rows or values and avoid duplicates in the following schema.

table schema is

```
id,subject1,subject2,subject3
```

id is auto incremented.
A duplicate would be where all subject1,subject2,subject3 already exist in a record in the exact same order.

```
INSERT INTO "table_name" ("subject1","subject2","subject3")  
VALUES ("cats", "dogs", "hamsters")  
VALUES ("squirrels", "badgers", "minxes")  
VALUES ("moose", "deer", "ocelots")
```

In the table let's say I already have a record for

```
id,subject1,subject2,subject3
1,"cats", "dogs", "hamsters"
```

so I want it to just insert

```
VALUES ("squirrels", "badgers", "minxes")  
VALUES ("moose", "deer", "ocelots")
```

I've seen answers about avoiding duplicates for single items, but not for 3.

Answer (score 3):

You want to add the `UNIQUE` constraint to your table.  If you write the `UNIQUE` constraint out separately, it becomes clearer how to apply it to arbitrary combinations of columns.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    subject1 VARCHAR(30),
    subject2 VARCHAR(30),
    subject3 VARCHAR(30),
    UNIQUE (subject1, subject2, subject3)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get around with the unique key on three columns.

Example of table definition

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'PK',
  `subject1` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `subject2` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `subject3` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `subjects` (`subject1`,`subject1`, `subject3`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: Awesome. I expected an answer in a few hours not 2-3 minutes. Stackoverflow is like lightning sometimes.

Comment: No prob, it just like doing crosswords, even better. It is interesting, sophisticated and useful for someone, so awesome!

Comment: @daniel: please don't forget about accepting answers, until now you have 0% of accepted answers, that is it is less stimulating to answer your questions. Read FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

To add the constraint in now:

```
ALTER TABLE {tablename}
ADD CONSTRAINT {constraintname} UNIQUE (subject1, subject2, subject3)
```