# how to avoid duplicates in a table check on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to make sure a combination of multiple columns is not inserted.

Lets say.

```
Emloyee

EmployeeId CatgoryId  BusinessId

1          1          1

2          2          1


BusessCategory

CategoryId BusinessId

1          1
1          2
1          3
2          1
2          4
2          3
```

I have to make sure no combination is repeated while inserting data in to the table.

my sql query would me some thing like

```
insert into employee(EmployeeId, CatgoryId,  BusinessId)
select e.employeeid,e.categoryid,bc.BusinessId from employee e inner join BusessCategory bc on bc.CatgoryId = e.CatgoryId
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what a repetition would be with the above data?

Comment: lets say 1 2 3 combination already present, so it should not allow any insertions with same combination.

Comment: What exactly is your question? A `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint prevents duplicates, and you mentioned below that you already have one, so it isn't clear what your problem is.

Comment: my select will return multiple records by applying multiple joins, in those selected records I want to ignore if the combination is already present in the table.

Comment: Wait you are inserting into the table your selecting from? I'm not necessarily sure what you are attempting to accomplish.

Comment: I know that, that is my business requirement.

Comment: You really have a column BusinessID in both the Employee table and BusessCategory table.  And you want to insert the value of BusinessId from the BusessCategory based on a join on CatgoryId.

Answer (score 3):

Define a unique key over all relevant columns. Then the DB will throw an error before inserting duplicates.

Comment: I've the unique key  defined, I want to insert only if there is no combination.

Comment: Then try to insert and catch the error or doa select before inserting. Or look into MSSQL `MERGE`

Answer (score 0):

@kumar: please find the duplicates of this question in a separate chain [how do i insert multiple values in mysql and avoid duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986137/how-do-i-insert-multiple-values-in-mysql-and-avoid-duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on whether you are trying to populate a table for the first time without duplicate rows or if you want to create a table that will not allow duplicate rows in the future (or possibly both).  If you want to prevent duplicate rows going forward then @juergen's answer should cover you.  If you want to populate the table for the first time with a distinct set of rows try the query below:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (A,B,C)
SELECT DISTINCT A,B,C FROM TABLE2
```

If you want to do both things then a combination of @jurgen and my answer should cover you.

Answer (score 0):

If bc.bc.CatgoryId is repeated in BusessCategory then you will get a row in the result for each match.

```
select e.employeeid,e.categoryid,bc.BusinessId 
from employee e 
inner join BusessCategory bc 
on bc.CatgoryId = e.CatgoryId
```

The easy answer is

```
select distinct e.employeeid,e.categoryid,bc.BusinessId 
from employee e 
inner join BusessCategory bc 
on bc.CatgoryId = e.CatgoryId
```

Comment: The query should work if i run it for multiple times.

Comment: If the data does not change then the query should return the same data each time it is run.  Have you tested it?

Comment: The above query will return distinct records that is fine, But it will not restrict the user resubmitting duplicate combination

Comment: To be clear you really have a column named BusinessId in both Employee and BusessCategory?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i am looking for:

```
insert into employee(EmployeeId, CatgoryId,  BusinessId)
select e.employeeid,e.CatgoryId,bc.BusinessId from employee e inner join BusessCategory bc 
on bc.CategoryId = e.CatgoryId 
where not exists(
select * from employee e1 where 
 bc.BusinessId = e1.BusinessId and e.CatgoryId = e1.CatgoryId and e.EmployeeId = e1.EmployeeId
)
```

welcome for any better solution.

Answer (score -3):

exact syntax may not match, but this one following may be a basic idea---

```
           insert into table (A,B,C)  values (a,b,c) where a is not in(select a from table where A=a  and B=b and C=c)
```

Comment: This is not a helpful answer because the syntax is invalid and the intention of your code is not clear